# Evaluation if-statement in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

There are two declared variables, I want to evaluate at same time if both exist (are TRUE).

```
my @array = (1,2);
my $scalar = 0;

if (@array && $scalar){
  print "success\n";
}
```

`&&` does not work. Is there another operator or do I have to create 2 if-state?
I expected it to print `success`.

Comment: an array itself is always true, do you want to check itÄs length maybe?

Comment: I want to check if it has elements.

Comment: works for me: http://ideone.com/bGfJyu

Comment: For future reference, "does not work" is a *terrible* description of of your problem. Tell us what unexpected behaviour you saw.

Comment: @Christoph an array is false (in boolean context) if it doesn't contain any items. `perl -E'my @a;say "false" unless @a'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that does not work is not the code you posted.

```
perl -E 'my @array = (1,2); my $scalar = 1; if (@array && $scalar) { say "True!" } else { say "False" }'
True!

perl -E 'my @array = (); my $scalar = 1; if (@array && $scalar) { say "True!" } else { say "False" }'
False
```

**Edit:** More examples in response to kmxillo's comment:

```
perl -E 'my @array = (1,2); my $scalar = 0; if (@array && $scalar) { say "True!" } else { say "False" }'
False

perl -E 'my @array = (1,2); my $scalar = 0; if (@array && defined $scalar) { say "True!" } else { say "False" }'
True!
```

The number 0 is considered to be a false value (along with `undef`, the empty string, the empty array, and the string "0"), so setting `$scalar` to 0 makes `@array && $scalar` false. To keep it true when `$scalar` is 0, test `defined $scalar` instead.

Comment: I declared scalar as 0, when if-statement was evaluated. it checked if it is `>0`

Comment: @kmxillo: Ah! In that case, your problem is with Perl's concept of "truth" - the number 0 is considered to be false. If you want it to return "true" when `$scalar` is 0, then use `defined $scalar` in the test. I'll edit my answer to also show this.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider array true when it has more than zero elements, then your if statement looks fine and should work as expected.

This program:

```
my @array = (1,2);
my $scalar = 1;

if (@array && $scalar) {
    print "TRUE!\n";
}
```

prints `TRUE`.

Why do you think `&&` does not work?

Comment: both variables have more than zero elements but  it does not work... as you said, it should work fine.

Comment: @kmxillo a scalar variable always has exactly one element, even when it is `undef`ined (`perl -E'say scalar @{[ $a ]}'`),
 or holding a reference to an array (`perl -E'$a=\@a; say scalar @{[ $a ]}'`).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  my @array = (1,2);
  my $scalar = 0;

  if (scalar @array && defined $scalar){
     print "success\n";
  }
```

Comment: [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) is not needed as the left side of [`&&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) is always in scalar context. Actually the right side of `&&` is also in a form of scalar context because of the [`if` statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).